# shared a database connection between more jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, transactions, connection, shared

I have a task that consist of 3 command sql; now, this 3 command are all insert and I must type data in textbox on the 3 jsp pages but I can execute the second and third command only after that I have execut ethe first insert command (so this 3 command must be execute in a unique transaction because there are constraints); moreover, after the execution of the first command, I must redirect to another jsp page because the interface to type the other data of 2nd and 3rd command isn't the same; my question is: there is a way to make only one connection, execute the 3 command into the 3 jsp pages and make commit manually only into the 3rd page in a single transaction?

I'm using only jsp, not servlet and I'M using eclipse with tomcat

Comment: You might be better off explaining your program without your technical details. What do you need to do?

Comment: make a single connection that is valid for each jsp page without create for each jsp a connection object; the target is make 3 sql command in a single transaction but this 3 sql command, for interface reason (gui), must be execute from 3 jsp page....